# Final Winter Bash 2013 standings for EL&U

Tags: discussion, winterbash-2013, winterbash

[Winter Bash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com) is now over and the site will soon be taken down.

What are the final [leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/english.stackexchange.com) standings for the EL&U site?

(Network screenshots can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215235/162511).)

Answer (score 8):

I would like to make special mention of our own favorite moderator, **RegDwight**, who not only topped the charts on our site, but also on many of the other sites.

Although three other users received more *unique* hats than Reg, Reg crushed the competition by earning an astounding ***604 hats*** total across the network, soundly thrashing his nearest competitor by a margin of 400%. Or so. I didn't do the math carefully.

Behold the beauty that hat fever produced:
[image: Reg's hat boards]

*image provided by Reg. Actually, he doesn't know I lifted it, so let's keep it between you and me.

Comment: Actually, Reg's nearest competitor in the total hats category is the 'Community' bot-user, with 585 total. That's about a 3% difference. His nearest presumably-human competitor is Gilles with 321 total hats, so about 47% fewer than Reg. Others with impressive total hat counts: Robert Cartaino (238), Nick Craver (231), Geoff Dalgas (224), Shog9 (219). (I only checked users with 9 or more distinct hats.)

Answer (score 5):

EL&U itself came a respectable 9th overall. Here's a screenshot of the top of our leaderboard:

[image: EL&U top 14]

Comment: I'd like to thank the academy.

Comment: I'd like to thank the hatcademy.